# Order mysqls MATCH() AGAINST() relevancy with full math at the top

Tags: mysql, match, match-against, against

I ran into a problem using mysqls MATCH()...AGAINST() today.

Because I guess it might be easier to adress my problem I created a small [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b60671/1/0).

I fully understand, why "Foo Bar Foo" is more relevant then "Foo Bar" in the way this Select statment works. But what I want is that "full matching" terms are treated with a higher relevancy then "full matching and a little bit more" terms.

```
title         relevance
Foo Bar       0.046829063445329666
Foo Bar Foo   0.031219376251101494
Foo           0
Bar           0
```

Is this result possible without using "union" to combine two statements?

Answer (thanks to Gordon Linoff):

```
SELECT *
FROM FOOBAR
WHERE title LIKE '%Foo Bar%'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN title LIKE 'Foo Bar%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) DESC,
         MATCH (title) AGAINST ('Foo Bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want in the `order by`.  One method would be to count the number of *different* words that match and then within each group, order by relevance ascending:

```
SELECT fb.*,
       MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+Foo +Bar' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM FOOBAR fb
ORDER BY ((case when title like '%Foo%' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when title like '%Bar%' then 1 else 0 end)
         ) desc,
         relevance asc
```

This does what you want for the example data.  It may not work in general, because the relevance calculation has other factors besides the number of times a word matches and the length of the string.

Comment: Thats what I wanted! Thanks! I'll update my startpost with my - slightly - modified version. :)